# Shift the values of a column by x rows in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I would like to shift the values of one column in a data frame by x rows(hours).

For example, in the following dataframe:

```
ind = pd.date_range('01 / 01 / 2000', periods=5, freq='12H')
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
               "B": [10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
               "C": [11, 22, 33, 44, 55],
               "D": [12, 24, 51, 36, 2]},
              index=ind)
```

I would like to shift the values in column A by two hours.

I use the following:

```
mask = (df.columns.isin(['A']))
cols_to_shift = df.columns[mask]
df[cols_to_shift] = df[cols_to_shift].shift(2,freq='H')
```

However, all column A's values are filled with NA. I guess it is because the values are shifted to hours that do not exist in the index column.

Is there a way to fix it?

This is the input:

[image]

And this is the output:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Try doing a `df['A'].dtype`.

Comment: Hi @Sid, at which stage?

Comment: After the `df` is made, before trying to add hours. Do you need the column to be of type `timedelta` or integer/float is ok?

Comment: @Thanasis - What is expected output?

Comment: hmm, I don't think I get your question. I want 5 more rows and to have the values of A in these rows, integer/float is ok(whatever the values are actually)

Comment: Ah..as jezrael pointed out please give expected output. I understood your question incorrectly.

Comment: I think how looks final DataFrame, how are changed A column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you could try assigning your `shifted` values, then use [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to extend your original `DataFrame`. I'm also using [`DataFrame.sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) and [`DataFrame.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) here to sort the results and deal with `NaN`:

```
# Example setup
ind = pd.date_range('01 / 01 / 2000', periods=5, freq='12H')
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
               "B": [10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
               "C": [11, 22, 33, 44, 55],
               "D": [12, 24, 51, 36, 2]},
              index=ind)

mask = (df.columns.isin(['A']))
cols_to_shift = df.columns[mask]
shifted = df[cols_to_shift].shift(2, freq='H')

df[cols_to_shift] = shifted
df = pd.concat([df, shifted]).sort_index().fillna(0)

print(df)
```

[out]

```
                       A     B     C     D
2000-01-01 00:00:00  0.0  10.0  11.0  12.0
2000-01-01 02:00:00  1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
2000-01-01 12:00:00  0.0  20.0  22.0  24.0
2000-01-01 14:00:00  2.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
2000-01-02 00:00:00  0.0  30.0  33.0  51.0
2000-01-02 02:00:00  3.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
2000-01-02 12:00:00  0.0  40.0  44.0  36.0
2000-01-02 14:00:00  4.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
2000-01-03 00:00:00  0.0  50.0  55.0   2.0
2000-01-03 02:00:00  5.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
```

Comment: after the df[cols_to_shift] = shifted, I get NaN in all the rows for A, although the shifted dataframe has the correct index and values.

Comment: hmmm I can't reproduce. Are you running any other lines either before or after what I've posted? Can I also ask what version of `pandas` you're using? I updated my answer to also include the example input data you provided. That full code block should return the above output

Comment: Pandas version is 0.21.0

Comment: Still, even if I copy the whole block from your answer, I get the error. I just run it in a new python console using Pycharm.

Comment: I can confirm it's working for me with version `0.24.1`, I'll try downgrading and see if I can find another solution

Comment: @Thanasis ok I downgraded and had to remove the `sort` arg from `concat` method. Can you try that?